# Is "like so" correct?

Tags: mistranslation

Reading blog entries about computing I often see "like so" instead of "like this". Is this correct English? It sounds to me like a word by word translation from German.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what German original you might have in mind. A word-for-word equivalent would be *wie so*, which makes no sense in German. To express *like this*, a German would typically write *(so) wie das*, *wie folgt*, simply *so*, or even *folgendermaßen*, but never *wie so*.

Comment: Could you give some examples?

Comment: never mind ... how do I delete this entry?

Comment: I wouldn't actually delete it. It *is* a valid question, whether or not the mistranslation hypothesis holds any water.

Comment: I have seen _like so_ in quite some places, and used quite frequently while talking when I was in Europe (Belgium). My impression was also the same - _perhaps_ a mistranslation from some language. Let me dig for links...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Like so" is completely valid English, and it comes from an older sense of the word *so* that is gradually falling out of use in English.  It should come as no surprise that *so* is a Germanic word and that the German *so* comes from the same place.

This meaning of *so* in English is "in this manner/condition".  [Dictionary.com touches on this meaning in the first three entries](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/so).

A lot of the places that we use *so* with this sort of meaning are in idiomatic phrases, for example:

- If you are **so** inclined...
- It is **so**.
- **So** let it be done.

I, for one, have said "like so" from time to time throughout my life.

Comment: Don't forget "Make it so."

Comment: @Claudiu: Good one!